# Error on empty (only Enter hit) cin buffer or load to value

Tags: c++, cin, enter, is-empty

It was easy to do a non-numerical value check, and it displays the error. The thing I'm having trouble with is when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is hit it does not display the error just waits for another input. Here is the code:

```
int x;

std::cout << "\nEnter level:\n";

if(!(std::cin >> x))
{
  std::cout << "Error";
  return ();                                
}
else 
  std::cout << "You have entered: " << x;

return(0);
```

Comment: Its different in the way that I can determent when a character is entered as shown here:   std::cin.getline(pa[x].fullname,SLEN);
            if(pa[x].fullname[0]=='\0')
            {
                std::cout << "Error";
                return (x);
            }      but I cant differentiate if a integer number was entered or just enter as shown here:   if((std::cin >> pa[x].ooplevel)==NULL)
                        {
                                std::cout << "Error";
                                return (x);                             
                        }

Comment: You are running in a loop, so the last `std::cin >> pa[x].ooplevel` leaves a newline in the input buffer. Also that condition doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have tried a couple of stuff as well as `std::cin >> pa[x].ooplevel`. the problem is that when I hit enter it just waits for an input but i want it to display a error.

Comment: Change that condition to `if(!(std::cin >> pa[x].ooplevel))` and don't forget to call `cin.clear()` and to consume the wrong input.

Comment: Ok I tried that but still same result when I only hit enter(without entering anything else) it just keeps waiting for input instead of displaying the error. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have been stuck at this for a while before I tried to write here and on reddit .

Comment: Post a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem, and I'll consider to lift the lock from your question.

Comment: Ok i hope now its fine.

Comment: In any case you should flush after printing the `"Error"`: `std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;`

Comment: Sry I'm trying to learn C++ so I'm still new to this.

Comment: You probably should better learn c++ from a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Stack Overflow isn't meant as a tutoring site.